# What license is DirectShow and what inputs and outputs can it handle?

Tags: licensing, directshow, codec

I want to create a project using DirectShow. Which license does DirectShow have? Can I just use it or do I have to mind sth.?

What input and output-codecs can DirectShow handle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Directshow with no issues.  The only issues you may have surround some of the codecs.  Some of those are licensed.  Distribution of those "can" get complicated.  In general (Though this isn't always the case so make sure you check the license!) decoders can be distributed freely but encoders need to be licensed in some form of other.

As for what input and output codecs it can use ... it can use pretty much anything with a DirectShow or DirectMedia Object built for it.  If there is a format there is usually an encoder/decoder for it.